# Wpf Grid with 2 Rows width sizing

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I am trying to work on this WPF design and not having any luck

This is the xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="namespace.myuserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
         Focusable="True"
         d:DesignHeight="10000" d:DesignWidth="1049">


<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DocumentGroup" Source="{Binding docs}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="type.Name"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="groupingHeaderTemplate">
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" Background="AliceBlue"></Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Focusable="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500" ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                  BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray" BorderThickness="1" Width="6" ShowsPreview="True"  >
        <GridSplitter.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF808385" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFECF1F7" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </GridSplitter.Background>
    </GridSplitter>
    <ScrollViewer >
        <ListBox  Grid.Column ="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="lstCustomList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DocumentGroup}}"

                  SelectionChanged="ShowDocument" >
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate= "{StaticResource groupingHeaderTemplate}"  />
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Label Name="clLabel"  Height="10000" Content="{Binding docResult, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Red"  Padding="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,7,0">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding docs.Count}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Focusable="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Width="300" Height="100">Launch</Button>
            <wpf:WebView2 Grid.Row="1" Name="View2"  />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `button` is not visible because you set `row` height to 50 but also `button` height to 100. I would set `row` height to `Auto` in this case.

White space on the right side in the second column is due to you've set main `grid` `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left`. Just remove it.

`WebView2` doesn't fill the space because the parent grid has `HorizontalAlignment` set to `Left`.

Here is updated xaml (main grid only)

```
...
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Focusable="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500" ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
              BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray" BorderThickness="1" Width="6" ShowsPreview="True"  >
        <GridSplitter.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF808385" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFECF1F7" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </GridSplitter.Background>
    </GridSplitter>
    <ScrollViewer >
        <ListBox  Grid.Column ="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="lstCustomList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DocumentGroup}}"

              SelectionChanged="ShowDocument" >
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate= "{StaticResource groupingHeaderTemplate}"  />
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Label Name="clLabel"  Height="10000" Content="{Binding docResult, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Red"  Padding="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,7,0">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding docs.Count}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Focusable="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Width="300" Height="100">Launch</Button>
            <wpf:WebView2 Grid.Row="1" Name="View2"  />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day.